# javadoc в многомодульном проекте maven

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

Всем привет. У меня есть многомодульный проект `maven`, в котором есть модуль `api`, для которого мне нужно сгенерировать `javadoc`. Как я могу сгенерировать `javadoc` не в папку `target` в модуле `api`, а в папку `target` родительского модуля. Сейчас я генерирую `javadoc` так:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>../target</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>aggregate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

`outputDirectory` не помогает от слова совсем: `javadoc` все равно создается в `api/target/site`

Для сборки проекта использую `mvn package`